# gradient fill violin plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to gradient fill a violin plot based on the density of points in the bins (blue for highest density and red for lowest).

I have generated a plot using the following commands but failed to color it based on density (in this case the width of the violin. I also would like to generate box plots with similar coloring).

```
library("ggplot2")
data(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut,y=carat)) + geom_violin()
```

Comment: Can you show a picture (drawing?) of your desired output? Why do you need the colors; doesn't the width of the violin already implicate density?

Comment: Hi Heroka, actually my final goal is to color the violin plot ( or the box plot which I prefer in my case due to space restrictions) based on another parameter. So I want to show  how the distribution of the let's say carats affect another variable; let say abundance. For example If diamonds with high carats are rare (just an assumption) then the violin plot region with larger width should be more blue and the narrow regions will be more reddish.

Comment: For the diamonds data set will it be possible to the fill the cut vs carats violin pots with price variable to show the relationship between the carat and the price.   Thanks!

Comment: ggplot does not support the filling of individual graphic objects with gradients. While it would certainly be possible to make the solid coloring of each box plot dependent on some variable, you can't create a gradient _within_ an individual box. There are probably ways to "hack around" the limitation and draw something that resembles a box plot with a gradient fill, but it'd be quite complex and defeats the point of using ggplot for simplicity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign a Colour Scale based on Y-axis in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077580/how-to-assign-a-colour-scale-based-on-y-axis-in-ggplot)

Answer (score 2):

to change the colour of the violin plot you use fill = variable, like this:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut,y=carat)) + geom_violin(aes(fill=cut))
```

same goes for boxplot

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut,y=carat)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cut))
```

[image]

but whatever value you have has to have the same value for each cut, that is, if you wanted to use for example mean depth/cut as the color variable you would have to code it.

with dplyr group your diamonds by cut and with summarize get the mean depth (or any other variable)

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds_group <- group_by(diamonds, cut)
diamonds_group <- summarize(diamonds_group, Mean_Price = mean(price))
```

Then I used diamonds2 as a copy of diamonds to then manipulate the dataset

```
diamonds2 <- diamonds
```

I merge both dataframes to get the Mean_Depth as a variable in diamonds2

```
diamonds2 <- merge(diamonds2, diamonds_group)
```

And now I can plot it with mean depth as a color variable

```
ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x=cut,y=carat)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Mean_Price)) + scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = mean(diamonds2$price))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks a lot! I was wondering if it will be possible to gradient fill each box separately based on price (blue for high; red for low price with mean colored as white).

Comment: @user2438149 I edited the answer, hopefully that is what you were looking for

Comment: I meant gradient filling each box separately based on it's price values; so 5 boxes each filled with gradient (both blue and red will be used for each box). thanks!

Comment: The five boxes should look more like the legend. so the mean price has to be calculated five times for each box and then gradient fill each box separately. This the analysis will not involve showing relationship between different cuts just and price; just each cut taken separately and show the relation between the carat and price. Given higher carat diamonds are costlier in general the upper end the each boxes will be more bluish and the lower parts will be reddish.  Sorry for not making it clearer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2438149, I think you can't do that. However, I have an alternative solution try this and see if you like it `ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x=cut,y=carat)) + geom_jitter(aes(color = price)) + scale_colour_gradient2(midpoint = mean(diamonds2$price))`

Comment: Good to know this one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just answered this [for another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67077580/7941188), but believe it's possibly more appropriate for this thread. You can create a pseudo-fill by drawing many segments. You can get those directly from the underlying data in the ggplot_built object.

If you want an additional polygon outline ("border"), you'd need to create this from the x/y coordinates. Below one option.

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut,y=carat)) + geom_violin() 

mywidth <- .35 # bit of trial and error

# all you need for the gradient fill 
vl_fill <- data.frame(ggplot_build(p)$data) %>%
  mutate(xnew = x- mywidth*violinwidth, xend = x+ mywidth*violinwidth) 

# the outline is a bit more convoluted, as the order matters
vl_poly <- vl_fill %>%
  select(xnew, xend, y, group) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(y, group), names_to = "oldx", values_to = "x") %>% 
  arrange(y) %>%
  split(., .$oldx) %>%
  map(., function(x) {
    if(all(x$oldx == "xnew")) x <- arrange(x, desc(y))
    x
    }) %>%
  bind_rows()

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = vl_poly, aes(x, y, group = group), 
               color= "black", size = 1, fill = NA) +  
  geom_segment(data = vl_fill, aes(x = xnew, xend = xend, y = y, yend = y,
                                   color = violinwidth))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: is there any update to this? Wonder if there's a simpler way to fill the violin with a gradient for density in an easier or an integrated way

Comment: @CyG not to my knowledge. Feel free to add an answer if you find a simpler solution!