# violin plot gradient fill in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gradient, violin-plot

I've been strugling to get a violin plot filled with a color gradient. What  I'm trying to get should be something similar to this (which I've made up using an image editor).

[image: This is similar to what I want]

I've tried  several codes around this idea

```
data("diamonds")
library (ggplot)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut,y=price))+
geom_violin(aes(fill=price))+
scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high = "green")
```

which gives me no fill color at all. I realise that it can be done using `geom_jitter` or something similar, but that's not what I want.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

PS. I've found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087157/gradient-fill-violin-plots-using-ggplot2) with no satisfactory answers

**EDIT** 15/04/2021: This question has been solved here:
[How to assign a Colour Scale based on Y-axis in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077580/how-to-assign-a-colour-scale-based-on-y-axis-in-ggplot)

Comment: Hi Jeronimo, to my knowledge it is not possible, one question though, if you are using price as the y axis, what are you trying to represent with the gradient, it would make sense to me if you were trying to get a third variable in there.

Comment: I've also never seen this, I don't think that functionality is supported

Comment: @DerekCorcoran Well, it is just for illustrative purposes. I've found that violin plots are useful, but not very intuitive. In my case, the numbers in the y axis are not meaningful because I'm plotting a ratio between two variables. I thought that adding the gradient scale to my violins would make them easier to understand. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Indeed!!!! Thank you so much @tjebo! It took a little long (4 years and 3 months) but I'm glad somebody figured it out!